# In PHP is a file pointer automatically closed when the function it is inside ends

Tags: php, pointers, fopen

I have tried googling this, tried reading the PHP manual for fclose(), but I can't find the answer to this question.

Say I have a PHP file with 2 functions: function A and function B.  I fopen() a file pointer in function A:

```
$filepointer = fopen( $file, 'w');
```

Let's say I DON'T fclose() the file pointer in function A, but function A reaches its end naturally.

Now I'm in function B.  Is the file pointer still available in function B ?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: If both the function is in same class, and $filepointer = fopen( $file, 'w'); is declared outside the function, then yes, it would be available in both function. However if you declare it inside a function, then its scope would be for that function, however lifetime would be until script ends.

Comment: I don't understand how the file pointer lifetime can be different from its scope.